# Disable python auto-escaping for environment variables

Tags: python

I am having the following problem with python, being used to generate
files on Linux, that are being read on Windows. Python is auto-escaping
the strings, so that when written to a file, they are incorrect.

In my shell I have the environment variable set to a UNC path:

```
camd011> setenv python_error "\\\\a\\b\\c"
camd011> echo $python_error 
\\a\b\c
```

I then retrieve this in python, as it will be used to generate C code
and a #include directive. However when I retrieve the value in python:

```
camd011> python
Python 1.6.1 (#1, Oct 17 2013, 15:08:20)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Copyright (c) 1995-2001 Corporation for National Research Initiatives.
All Rights Reserved.
Copyright (c) 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam.
All Rights Reserved.
>>> import os
>>> value = os.environ['python_error']
>>> value
'\\\\\\\\a\\\\b\\\\c'
```

As you can see above it has been auto-escaped, thus when I write it to a file:

```
>>> f = open("temp.txt", "w")
>>> f.write(value)
>>> f.close()
```

I end up with double-slashes, instead of a proper UNC path, and the code
now fails to compile. File:

```
\\\\a\\b\\c
```

i.e. the code includes a #include which now fails:

```
#include "\\\\a\\b\\c\file.h"
```

How do I stop python from auto-escaping my environment variable?

Comment: Python 1.6.1?! Wow, blast from the distant past! In any case, I cannot reproduce this on Python 2.7. What shell is it you are using here?

Comment: Is the shell relevant. I am using Red Hat Enterprise 6, with either csh or tcsh. Although the same behaviour has been seen on Ubuntu 10 and 11.

Comment: It *could* be, depending on how the vars are exported to child processes. But I suspect that you have a bug unique to the rather outdated Python version here.

Comment: I can reproduce this with tcsh 6.17 and Python 2.7. Doesn't happen with bash, appears to be a tcsh problem?

Comment: Other people have logged into my machine, and not observed the same behaviour. It works OK for them. I have logged into other peoples machines, and seen the same problem. Is there something that will control how vars are exported to child processes, which could cause the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with quoting and dequoting in `tcsh`. It has nothing to do with Python -- Python gets the same variable that you can print out with the `env` command.

It appears that in tcsh, `echo $FOO` de-quotes the value of `$FOO` before printing. This seems to have misled you about what is really in your environment variable, so you've added an extra layer of quoting.

```
unaha-closp:~> setenv FOO "\\hello\world"
unaha-closp:~> echo $FOO
\hello\world
unaha-closp:~> env | grep FOO
FOO=\\hello\world
unaha-closp:~> python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ["FOO"]
\\hello\world
>>>
unaha-closp:~> bash
svk@unaha-closp:~$ echo $FOO
\\hello\world
```

The proper `setenv` command should simply be `setenv python_error "\\a\b\c"`.

Comment: This works. If I echo it out it looks wrong, but it is set correctly when I look at the value with env. Thanks.